# Getting VS Code to detect React props properly when Redux state props are mixed in

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, react-redux

There is a [nice example in the React-Redux documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#manually-typing-connect) on how to build a functional component that will receive both props from Redux and from its parent component:

Here is the code from that [example](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#manually-typing-connect). Mind you, I renamed the component MyComponent2 since I already had one called MyComponent:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

interface StateProps {
  isOn: boolean
}

interface DispatchProps {
  toggleOn: () => void
}

interface OwnProps {
  backgroundColor: string
}

type Props = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps

const mapState = (state: StateProps) => ({
  isOn: state.isOn,
})

const mapDispatch = {
  toggleOn: () => ({ type: 'TOGGLE_IS_ON' }),
}

const MyComponent2 = (props: Props) => (
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor }}>
    <button onClick={props.toggleOn}>
      Toggle is {props.isOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
    </button>
  </div>
)

// Typical usage: `connect` is called after the component is defined
export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(MyComponent2)
```

However, when I try to use that component in another one, VS Code is complaining about this component properties:

[image]

Is anything wrong with the code or is it VS Code getting confused? And in any case, what would be the proper solution to fix this?

For the sake of completion, here is the code of the parent component. Note that it is a class component and that I am looking for a solution where the child component would also eventually be a class component:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import MyComponent2 from '../MyComponent2'

interface IMyMainComponentProps {
  name: string,
  color: string
}

interface IMyMainComponentState {
  humor: string
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IMyMainComponentState) => ({
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
};

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export class MyMainComponent extends React.Component<IMyMainComponentProps, IMyMainComponentState> {
  constructor(props?: IMyMainComponentProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      humor: 'happy'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
        <div>
          {this.props.color}
        </div>
        <div>
          <MyComponent2 backgroundColor='white' />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

I have MyComponent2 displaying fine on CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-class-components-forked-js2e2h?file=/src/App.tsx

So, I really don't know what it different in my VS Code on my computer:

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-class-components-forked-js2e2h?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I don't see why you would expect `isOn` to be optional in `MyComponent2`?

Comment: Either make the `isOn` property optional in your `StateProps` interface, or include the property when instantiating `MyComponent2`.

Comment: Not sure what's going on in the sandbox (without looking too deeply). I would expect to see an typescript error there too.

Comment: isOn is provided by mapState, but you might be right; there is nothing telling this to VS Code.

Comment: However, CodeSandbox has not problem determining the proper props for my component. Check MyComponent2 (not MyComponentV2) on 
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-class-components-forked-js2e2h?file=/src/App.tsx